# is it possible to create an exe that gives me an interface to write things into a DB?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to create an exe that you click and it opens an interface with a textbox and inside that textbox whatever you type, gets added into a MySQL db after you hit submit?

I would add the info into a DB using PHP but maybe use VB or something else that would allow me that easy interface whenever I need it to put text into a box and submit it and that exe will send the data to the php script to write into MySQL.

I know that I can create an interface or form using php and submit that to write text into MySQL but I want to use an exe instead, a quick easy icon on my computer that I can click and input the text to enter into the DB rather than going to a url for the interface.

Any ideas?

Comment: why not just use Mysql command prompt?

Comment: Strictly speaking, there's no need for PHP at all, assuming this is all running on a secure, internal network.  VB should be able to write to mysql itself.  PHP is only handy if you want to write a secure webservice to manage access to mysql.

Comment: Of-course. MySql has a command prompt for doing such stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course its possible.

In this case though.. why not just use a MySQL GUI such as [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/)?

Comment: So why do you want to use an EXE? Personally, I wouldn't trust somebody giving me an EXE file to do something I could do through a web interface just as easily. You can even make an icon on the clients' desktops that's a shortcut to the webform.

Comment: That would work too, icon for shortcut to webform. Great idea! Can you please briefly suggest how I can do that?

Comment: In Windows it's as simple as highlighting the full url in your address bar and dragging it to your desktop (or dragging the little icon that sits to the left of the URL).

Answer (score 2):

There is a pretty good selection of software that lets you do exactly this.

- [**PHPMyAdmin**](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) is popular, but I have found it to be clunky and too intrusive.
- Part of the MySQL project, **[MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)** seems well-supported, though I have not used it
- The [**open-sourced version of SQLYog**](http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/downloads/list) is a Windows client that I've been using for years, and it seems to get the job done well.

Comment: the whole interface would scare a user that has no knowledge of softwares. By keeping it to a simple icon to click and enter text into a box, then hitting submit makes it very easy to use. This way eve nthe users with the brain developement of a 4 year old could use this.

Comment: @Nadal I don't think you generally expect somebody with "no knowledge of softwares" to be running queries directly against your database.

Comment: think of a form that a user submits. Does the user know in the back end that they are making changes to a MySQL DB? the user has no idea what is going on at the login scree nor what happens upon submittion.

Comment: @Nadal Oh, in that case you need to rewrite your question.  What you are describing is most software, ever, anywhere.  Almost every business application involves text-field based interface that saves data in a database.